# Turn PrtScr off in Firefox

Tags: screenshot

I was trying to capture some language in a video and used the PrtScr button several times (didn't work). Now the full screen is overlaid with grey and at the bottom of the screen is a bright rectangle where the controls for the "Take Screenshot" function used to appear. I can't make it go away. Where do I need to look/ask?

Comment: System specifications and if possible a screenshot

Comment: You've not provided release details (*and desktop if using a Ubuntu flavor*), but if I hit PrintScreen and a *screenshot* dialog appears (*this dialog can vary on release & desktop being used*) which allows me to select screen position/window etc.. I can usually cancel it by just pressing ESC (*it's possible some use different keys, but they're usually easy to guess.. alas you gave no release/desktop details*)

Answer (score 1):

The Gnome screenshot tool (Ubuntu 22.04 and newer) has a close (`X`) icon. Click it.

Or use the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.